# Echo calculation to text file

Tags: shell, output, numeric-data, expr

I am working on a project to calculate my overtime at work with a shell script.  I have two inputs and want to find if my number is over 800 = 8 hours;
if it is bigger, then it has to print out the result to my text file. 
It has to print out my difference.

```
if [ $var1 -gt 800 ]; then
`expr $var1-800`
echo Overtime: "" >> $path
```

and then I'm lost because I don't how to print out the result of my calculation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using modern bash (don't use backticks or `expr`) :

```
if ((var1 > 800)); then
    overtime=$((var1 - 800)) # variable assignation with the arithmetic 
    echo "Overtime: $overtime"
fi
```

Or simply :

```
if ((var1 > 800)); then
    overtime="Overtime: $((var1 - 800))" # concatenation of string + arithmetic
fi
```

Check [*bash arithmetic*](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arith_expr)

Comment: Hi, sorry think my explaining was wrong.. 
I type my checkin: 700 = 7:00 am 
then checkout: 1800 = 6:00pm
Then I gotta find the difference from 1800-700 if over 800 it gotta print out the result

Comment: And so ? Can't you just adapt the command ? You have all what you need. It's simple arithmetic. Doesn't this snippet get clear ?

Comment: I'll try as I wrote im way to new to this... to make a project like this

Comment: I do, im just new to programming with arithmetic and how its done in scripts

Comment: Added comments in my snippet

Answer (score 0):

```
if (( var1 > 800 )); then
    printf 'Overtime: %d\n' "$(( var1 - 800 ))" >>"$path"
fi
```

`expr` and backticks are antiquated, and you don't even need a command substitution here.