# find last entered number after finding file

Tags: bash, shell

My question is kinda long
Im trying to make a check in and out system simple, a menu with options 1 checkin and 2 checkout at the end of the day when I go home.
My file contains:

```
Dato: 22-02-2018    
Mødt ind: 700    
Gået hjem: 1600    
Overtid:    
Dato: 23-02-2018    
Mødt ind: 730    
Gået hjem: 1600
Overtid:
```

I gotta find difference for 730 and 1600 in this file.. and if the number is higher than 800 it gotta print the number if there is a difference 
hope you understand my question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Echo calculation to text file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/425889/echo-calculation-to-text-file)

Comment: Didn't you ask this same question here?: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/425889/echo-calculation-to-text-file

Comment: Someone told me to ask a new question , because my first question wasn't clear enough..

Comment: at least, post the expected result

Comment: I'll try and do that next time! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's the `Overtid:` that you want to fill out, then the following does that:

```
awk 'function overtime(s,e) {
         if (s) printf("Overtid: %d\n", (e - s > 800) ? e - s : 0);
     }
     /^Mødt ind:/  { start = $NF; print } 
     /^Gået hjem:/ { end   = $NF; print } 
     /^Dato:/      { overtime(start, end); print }
     END           { overtime(start, end) }' file
```

This picks out the start and end times from the data and for each `Dato:` line (which signifies a new record in the data), it prints out the overtime for the previous record.  This is also done at the end (the `END` block).

I've done `overtime()` as a function as we need to do the same thing in two different places in the script.  The `if (s)` in the function is to ensure that we don't get a bogus `Overtid: 0` output when hitting the very first `Dato:` line in the data.

The `print` statements in the code passes through the existing data to the output.

Output with your data:

```
Dato: 22-02-2018
Mødt ind: 700
Gået hjem: 1600
Overtid: 900
Dato: 23-02-2018
Mødt ind: 730
Gået hjem: 1600
Overtid: 870
```

Comment: is that gonna make a new file or is that gonna be printed out to my original file? kinda new to all of this programming, just wanna understand it

Comment: @peter This will, as it's written now, just output it on the terminal.  To output to a new file, just add `>newfilename` at the end of the command (after the input filename).  Do _NOT_ use the same name for the output file as for the input file.